# Google Sheets Formula Import Range with Indirect

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have this formula and want the reference to Archery to reference `Archery` which will be in Cell E1. I tried using the indirect formula but can't get it to work with the formatting for Google Sheets.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("SheetLocation", "Archery!A4:E3000"),"SELECT Col3,Col2 WHERE Col1 like '%TRUE%'")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **E1** contains the word **`Archery`** you need to do this:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID", E1&"!A4:E3000"), "select Col3,Col2 where Col1 like '%TRUE%'")
```